# Half Number pyramid in python

Tags: python, algorithm, numbers

How can I get a 'half-pyramid' of numbers using python ?

The user is asked for the height of the pyramid.

```
lines = int(raw_input("No. of lines:"))
```

The output is a half-pyramid of numbers.

For example, if the no. of lines is 5, I should get the following output -

```
1
23
456
78910
11121314
```

Double digit integers(like 11, 14 etc) can be considered as one

Comment: What have you tried? And what is the definition of a "half-pyramid" of numbers?

Comment: It's sort of a classic homework problem, @Michael - see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13077491/pyramid-of-numbers-in-python

Comment: Shouldn't the last line in the example be `1112131415` then? I was wondering if the number of digits in each number actually mattered

Answer (score 3):

Here's my take on it; the first line can be removed when using Python 3, but with it it'll work on both Python 2 and 3:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from itertools import count, islice
counter = count(1)
print(*(''.join(map(str, islice(counter, i + 1))) for i in range(lines)), sep='\n')
```

It certainly produces the expected output:

```
>>> from itertools import count, islice
>>> lines = 5
>>> counter = count(1)
>>> print(*(''.join(map(str, islice(counter, i + 1))) for i in range(lines)), sep='\n')
1
23
456
78910
1112131415
```

Comment: This is perfect for Snork since it clearly matches his level of expertise. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry it's in java, but you can easily adapt it in python I think!

```
int numberOutput=1;
for (int i =0;i<lines;i++){
for (int j = 0;j<i+1;j++){
System.out.print(numberOutput);
numberOutput++;
}
System.our.print("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
no_lines = int(raw_input("Enter no of lines : "))
a=0;
val=1
for i in range(1,no_lines+1):
    tmp_str = "";
    for q in range(0,i):
        tmp_str = tmp_str+str(val)
        val=val+1
    print tmp_str
```