# trying to solve number pyramid using for loops

Tags: python

I'm trying to code this figure in python

```
      1
    2 1 2
  3 2 1 2 3 
4 3 2 1 2 3 4
```

but I can only get the right side like this

```
1
1 2
1 2 3 
1 2 3 4
```

using this code:

```
def main ():


  # create pattern 1
  for i in range (1, 7,+1):
    for j in range (1, i + 1):
      print (j, end = " ")
    print ()
  print ()


main()
```

Seems like the easiest way to do these is using for loops, but how can I get the left side? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pyramid of numbers in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13077491/pyramid-of-numbers-in-python)

Comment: I did look at that but it didn't seem to help

Comment: @physicsmajor how does it not help? It's literally the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
for i in range(1,7,+1):
    for l in range(7-i,1,-1):
        print("  ",end="")
    for k in range(i,1,-1):
        print(k,end=" ")
    for j in range(1,i+1):
        print(j, end= " ")
    print()
print()
```

I just added 2 more for loops

> l for loop for spaces
>
> k for loop for left side numbers

Output:

```
          1 
        2 1 2 
      3 2 1 2 3 
    4 3 2 1 2 3 4 
  5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 
6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Comment: I don't completely understand, but pointing out that I needed a loop for spaces, as well as left numbers, makes it a bit clearer. I will study your code in detail to see how it all works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just try to use `^` alignment options.

> `^`   Forces the field to be centered within the available space.

```
num = 10

width = len(" ".join(map(str, range(num, 0, -1))) + " ".join(map(str, range(2, num + 1)))) + 1

print("{0:^{1}}".format("1", width))

for i in range(2, num + 1):
    part1 = " ".join(map(str, range(i, 0, -1)))
    part2 = " ".join(map(str, range(2, i + 1)))
    print("{0:^{1}}".format(" ".join((part1, part2)), width))
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know Python. But you can explain the concept that can help.

You should print the blanks as long as they do not print numbers.

One line of the pyramid consists of a blank, a numeric output in reverse order, a numeric output (except the first), and a blank output.

For example, if the limit of a number is 4, the first line will have 3 blanks, 1 reverse output, 0 normal output, and 3 blank output.

I hope it will be of help.